# Monodroid save image from url

Tags: image, url, xamarin.android

Hello the app that I'm building works with alot of images that are stored on the server and need to display them on a listview. I would like to be able to store them on a file.

so far here is the code I have

```
var imageUrl = new Java.Net.URL(obj.imageUrl);
var bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(imageUrl.OpenStream());
var image = new Android.Graphics.Drawables.BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

but I don't know how to save the image or where to save it.

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You're overthinking this. :-)

Once you have a `Stream`:

```
var imageUrl = new Java.Net.URL(obj.imageUrl);
System.IO.Stream stream = imageUrl.OpenStream();
```

you can just save it to disk:

```
using (var o = File.Open(
        Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
            "file-name"))) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int r;
    while ((r = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
        o.Write (buf, 0, r);
}
```

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` returns $APPDIR/files, which is [Context.FilesDir](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Context.FilesDir). You don't necessarily need to use this; [Context.CacheDir](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=P%3aAndroid.Content.Context.CacheDir) may be more appropriate.

Comment: thanks jonp. I think cache would be best but just to make sure is this the path i should use? System.Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache

Comment: never mind jonp **this.ApplicationContext.CacheDir.ToString();** figured it out. But hey thanks alot for you code I really appreciate it!